# Taxpayer Information Storage With Arrays

Tags: java

So what if I were to ask "x" amount of tax

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the `children` and `grossIncomes` array before the `do-while` loop.

Extend the do-while loop till `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message);`

Do not use `numTaxpayers` as index of `children` and `grossIncomes`. Use `count`, and initialize count to 0, before the loop starts.

```
            int[] children = new int[numTaxpayers];
            double[] grossIncomes = new double[numTaxpayers];
            int count = 0;
            while (count < numTaxpayers)
            {
                int numChildren = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many children do you have?"));
                double grossIncome = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your gross income?"));

                children[count] = numChildren;
                grossIncomes[count] = grossIncome;

                count ++;
                // Calculations goes here
                //....
                //...
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message);
             }
```

Comment: This is correct, but once you extend the loop, you should initialize your arrays (`double[] grossIncomes` and `int[] children`) before the while loop. Then the while loop, and use `count` instead of `numTaxpayers`.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning the `numChildren` and `grossIncome` variables in your loop rather than storing them:

```
    do
    {
        numChildren = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many children do you have?"));
        grossIncome = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your gross income?"));
        count ++;
    } while (count <= numTaxpayers);
```

Should be

```
final int[] children = new int[numTaxpayers];
final double[] grossIncomes = new double[numTaxpayers];
for(int i = 0; i < numTaxpayers; ++i) {
    children[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many children do you have?"));
    grossIncomes[i] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your gross income?"));
}
```

So you create your arrays and then you, for each tax payer, assign its array element to the results of your queries.

I would further suggest that you encapsulate your `TaxPayer` as an object and keep the methods related to them in that object.

```
public class TaxPayer {

   private final int numChildren;
   private final int grossIncome;

   private TaxPayer(final int numChildren, final int grossIncome) {
       this.numChildren = numChildren;
       this.grossIncome = grossIncome;
   }

   public static TaxPayer requestTaxPayerDetails() {
       final int numChildren = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many children do you have?"));
       final int grossIncome = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your gross income?"));
       return new TaxPayer(numChildren, grossIncome);
   }

   public int findTaxDependency() {
       // do stuff
   }

   public double calculateTax() {
      // do stuff
   }
}
```

And then

```
final List<TaxPayer> taxpayers = new LinkedList<TaxPayer>();
for(int i = 0; i < numTaxpayers; ++i) {
    taxpayers.add(TaxPayer.requestTaxPayerDetails());
}
```

A bit neater, no?

Comment: So don't use a do-while loop?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you use. You need to _keep_ the values you read. You are reassigning the values each iteration. A `for` loop is much simpler in any case.